# Spawn threads in a Spring RestController

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, tomcat, thread-safety

I have a bit of a strange question about threading... need some advice.

I am running my Spring4 webapp on Tomcat8. I have configured restful endpoint using Spring MVC to pick up requests going to "/rs/event/book/create"

```
@RequestMapping( 
        value = { "/rs/event/book/create" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public String bookCreate( @RequestBody Map<String,Object> jsonData ) { ... }
```

I will be making an Ajax call to this URL from the UI from time to time when the time is right.

I want the request going to "/rs/event/book/create" to fire three threads each making an HTTP call to Zapier and falling through, without waiting for a response from Zapier or the client waiting for a response from "/rs/event/book/create" ( this is a temporary thing, almost like a POC until we have time to figure out a more elegant solution ).

The issue is that I am afraid to just spawn threads ad-hoc and than not finishing or becoming zombies.

What is the best / safest way to spawn three disposable threads so just that the request going to "/rs/event/book/create" will fire the three threads and fall through? ( I am not talking about Spring @Async )

Thank you for you help friends!

**UPDATE**

I guess what I am really asking for here is if this is enough for me to not get in trouble long term?

```
@RequestMapping( 
        value = { "/rs/event/book/create" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public String bookCreate( @RequestBody Map<String,Object> jsonData ) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            // HTTP call to Zapier
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            // HTTP call to Zapier
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            // HTTP call to Zapier
        }
    }.start();

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Might be better to send messages to a queue.

Comment: Yes I agree! in a perfect scenario with a good implementation it would make a lot of sense to queue these as tasks. As I have said in the post, I don't have the time to do it the correct / perfect way at the moment.

Comment: If you are just forwarding on  a response from an external server, and your web app is not going to do anything with it, get the client's browser to do the get/post with ajax or something.

Comment: You don't need separate threads. This is exactly the sort of thing that a thread pool, managed by an executor, is for.

Comment: @Snickers3192 cannot do that, CROSS origin issues because it's going to a Zapie domain over HTTPs, has to be a server-side HTTP call

Comment: @chrylis, I have nothing against using a thread pool ( ThreadPoolExecutor ), question is will that guarantee that the threads are terminated correctly and I do not have zombies floating around after the app is running for weeks? :)

Comment: You *don't* terminate the threads--you don't ever create them in the first place. You create runnables and dispatch them into the thread pool, which manages the thread lifecycle.

Comment: @chrylis sounds like a plan! thank you for the tip I will see how the app behaves over time for the next couple of days!